# Posting XML Payload to server to retrieve values

Tags: xml, post, payload

[image]

I am creating a python webscraper that receives data for a client. The script should scrape the current 2020 value worth of the realestate adres that was input by client. But first I am trying to send a payload to get the data to work from their website.

The script is as following:

```
import requests
xml = """<wfs:GetFeature xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" outputFormat="application/json"><wfs:Query typeName="wozloket:woz_woz_object" srsName="EPSG:28992" xmlns:WozViewer="http://WozViewer.geonovum.nl" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"><ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"><ogc:And><ogc:And><ogc:Contains><ogc:PropertyName>wobj_geometrie</ogc:PropertyName><gml:Point xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><gml:pos>132840 502370</gml:pos></gml:Point></ogc:Contains><ogc:BBOX><ogc:PropertyName>wobj_geometrie</ogc:PropertyName><gml:Envelope xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><gml:lowerCorner>132839 502369</gml:lowerCorner><gml:upperCorner>132841 502371</gml:upperCorner></gml:Envelope></ogc:BBOX></ogc:And><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo matchCase="true"><ogc:PropertyName>wobj_bag_obj_id</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>385010000000664</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo></ogc:And></ogc:Filter></wfs:Query></wfs:GetFeature>"""
        
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "1116",
    "Content-Type": "text/xml",
    "Cookie": "_1aa19=http://10.0.2.97:8080; stg_returning_visitor=Sat%2C%2020%20Mar%202021%2009:19:46%20GMT; JSESSIONID=66E2234CBFF91B8F681359FC2D91345B; stg_traffic_source_priority=1; stg_externalReferrer=; _pk_ses.49d516ae-c5e9-11e7-aae6-0017fa104e46.b995=*; _pk_id.49d516ae-c5e9-11e7-aae6-0017fa104e46.b995=7d64f6d935881284.1616226862.2.1616243885.1616239478.; stg_last_interaction=Sat%2C%2020%20Mar%202021%2012:38:06%20GMT",
    "Host": "www.wozwaardeloket.nl",
    "Origin": "https://www.wozwaardeloket.nl",
    "Referer": "https://www.wozwaardeloket.nl/index.jsp",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Google Chrome\";v=\"89\", \"Chromium\";v=\"89\", \";Not A Brand\";v=\"99\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
    "User-Agent": "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"

}
var = requests.post('https://www.wozwaardeloket.nl/woz-proxy/wozloket', data=xml, headers=headers)
print(var.text)
```

Is there any python developer that could help me out? I will pay you a nice tip if you help me to get the values giving by their API. Currently I keep getting {"error" : "Maximum attempts reached for requests"} and have tried multiple things like different User- Agents etc.

Please someone bring me the knowledge! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same, try to first open a session with a get request to https://www.wozwaardeloket.nl/index.jsp?a=1&accept=true& before sending your post.
for me it is working in postman.

Comment: Yeah I had to exactly copy and customize the cookie on the first call and als had to put the exact coordinates from the map in the payload.

Problem is solved topic van be closed.